# Getting an error that a property doesn't exist when it is showing up on the page accurately

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm calling a twitter API from angular and then node, but I'm getting an error that a property doesn't exist  on type 'Object'. But it is showing up on the page properly.

I've tried renaming the property and looked through the tweet service that I have set up, but I can't seem to figure out what's going wrong.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TweetService } from '../../services/tweet.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-twitter-page',
  templateUrl: './twitter-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./twitter-page.component.scss']
})
export class TwitterPageComponent implements OnInit {

  tweetsArray;

  constructor(
    private twitter: TweetService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.twitter.getTweets().subscribe(tweet => {

      this.tweetsArray = tweet.tweets[0];
      console.log(this.tweetsArray);
    });
  }
}
```

Error:

```
ERROR in src/app/main-body/twitter-page/twitter-page.component.ts(20,32): error TS2339: Property 'tweets' does not exist on type 'Object'.
```

Comment: "cast" tweet in subscribe `subscribe((tweet:any)=>{....})`

Comment: @Eliseo Thanks that worked out perfectly! If you add your answer below I'll accept it as the best one, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here tweet is of the type Object which do not have attributes on it.

You should define an interface `ITweet` and cast tweet to this interface. This gives a shape to the tweet object and defines the set of attributes available on it.

tweet.ts -

```
export interface ITweet {
...
};
```

twitter-page.component.ts - (note - `.subscribe((tweet:ITweet) => {})`)

```
import { ITweet } from './tweet.ts';
.
.
.
export class TwitterPageComponent implements OnInit {
.
.
.

  ngOnInit() {
      this.twitter.getTweets().subscribe((tweet:ITweet) => {

        this.tweetsArray = tweet.tweets[0];
        console.log(this.tweetsArray);
      });
    }    
}
```

Or alternatively you can just cast tweet to any (`.subscribe((tweet:any) => {})`). But this is not recommended since you will lose the benefit of type checking.